# Formula based around dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to write a formula that will indicate when coverage of a specific product will go into effect based on the purchase date. Per the rules in this line of business, if a customer purchases a product after the 1st of any given month, the paid coverage of the product defaults to the 1st of the following month.

E.g. Customer Agreement starts 2/4/2019, so coverage would default to 3/1/2019; however, if the Agreement starts 2/1/2019, coverage would default to the same date (2/1/2019)

Is it possible to write a formula that will suit my needs where any order placed on the 1st of the month would start coverage same day, while all other dates would default to the 1st of the following month?

I have a formula along similar lines that but it serves a different purpose:
K185 = the Agreement Start Date
I90 = Invoice Date

```
=IF(OR(I90='2b - LookUp Values-UI'!K185,I90=TODAY()),"PASS","FAIL")
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DAY()` if the day of the month in A1 is not `1` then it will add on month and return the 1st of the following month.

```
=IF(DAY(A1)=1,A1,DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1))
```